# XKBSET mousekeys is buggy

Tags: linux, x11

So i run mousekeys using the same command every time:
`xkbset ma 60 10 10 5 2`
yet every time i strike `/` or `-`, mousekey's start glitching.

The glitch is:
when i use the numpad to move my mouse, instead of moving fluently, it starts to jump down. For example before i strike the `/` and `-` keys the numpad moves the mouse smoothly only several pixels at a time... when i strike any of those two keys, then the mouse pointer starts to move around 100 pixels.

**Update**
I now notice that when i have my **universal access** screen open, when i hit either of the two buttons, the **mouse keys** on/off switch turns to on. I feel as if this was the problem... is there a way to prevent that?